# StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync() doesn't return all files

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a project folder in Windows Phone 8 project with GPX files and some JPG images.

I'm trying to use `StorageFolder`'s `GetFilesAsync()` method to get all files from the folder:

```
var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("path");
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
```

However, I only get the JPG files in `files` list. It looks like GPX files are ignored. How could I get them? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid error.

The `BuildAction` property of the GPX files was set to `None`. Setting it to `Content` solved the problem, and now all the files are returned.